# How to use Shoulda matchers to test date validation

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, shoulda

I validate a date field as follows:

validates :return_date, inclusion: {in:(Date.today+1.day..Date.today+4.weeks)}

I test it using Rspec syntax as follows:

```
it "should only accept return date that is later than the current date" do
    quotation_request = FactoryGirl.build(:quotation_request, return_date: Date.today)
    expect(quotation_request.valid?).to be_falsy
end
```

The validation in the Quotation Request Model:

```
validates :return_date, inclusion: {in:(Date.today+1.day..Date.today+4.weeks)
```

This works. I was wondering if there was a way to use the Shoulda matchers to test this and if so which one and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use a proc for the evaluation of the dates

```
validates :return_date, inclusion: { in: ->(model) { (Date.today+1.day)..(Date.today+4.weeks) } }
```

Then yon can make adjustments to the given field to see when it is false and true

```
# Set the expectation that the factory is setup correctly
expect(quotation_request).to be_valid

# Then check that values "just" out of range make it invalid
quotation_request.return_date = Date.today
expect(quotation_request).not_to be_valid

quotation_request.return_date = Date.today+4.weeks+1.day
expect(quotation_request).not_to be_valid
```

Comment: I added the validation I use for the date to make what I'm testing clearer

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a better description of how to solve the  problem you're having @chell

Comment: Thanks Nort. I tried to use the proc as you show but it produces errors that the wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). Doesn't this built in Rails date work the same as a proc anyway?

Comment: @chellapparently the inclusion validation sends the *model itself* into the proc and I've again updated the post to match this -- hope this helps